# Web3.py Could not transact with/call contract function, is contract deployed correctly and chain synced?

Tags: ganache, web3.py

I am trying to call a contract function deployed in Ganache. I am pretty sure the contract is deployed because I can transact() and work with other functions. But when I call() it, I get this error:

> Could not transact with/call contract function, is contract deployed
> correctly and chain synced?

this is my function call:

```
 updated_card = magic_ideas.functions.get_card('731759').call()
```

Previously, I have to "deploy an exam" with this code and it works correctly:

```
 t_hash1 = magic_ideas.functions.new_card('title', 'example_text', 'www.card.com', '731759').transact()
```

I get a t_hash1. Then when I try to `get_card` using `.call()` I get the error. What am I missing?

**EDIT**

This is the contract declaration:

```
magic_ideas = w3.eth.contract(address="0x246eCb1dA50199FD7FcC20Ad08C617C52e34b128", abi=abi)
```

The abi is a copy & paste from remix.

Comment: I am also having the same issue.

Comment: Would help to answer your question if one would know the full source code needed to understand the problem and then the error message 

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa What part of the code do you think is missing? the connection is pretty straightforward ` w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('http://127.0.0.1:7545'))` . I'll add the contract declaration, if I need to add something else, let me know and I'll add it.

Comment: Suggest replicating the problem in a small code base so you can post the complete source code and people can get to the bottom of it.

Comment: Please post a compelte source code for a repeatable problem, so we do not need to guess what goes to variables and such. Then we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

use:

`updated_card = magic_ideas.functions.get_card('731759').transact()`

instead of

`updated_card = magic_ideas.functions.get_card('731759').call()`

Answer (score 1):

I found that calling the contract function first works.  This is supposed to clone the contract function (NOT the contract) and return a copy, but it also corrects the args field.  I believe this only works if there are zero arguments, however.

Example:

```
updated_card = magic_ideas.functions.get_card('731759')().call()
```

Note the extra set of parenthesis before `.call()`.

Comment: Thank you. This helped me and worked for me. Without the extra set of parentheses, this was not working.